# What is the order of operations to verify a transaction?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, mining

I am not asking if all nodes run each transaction.  I'm asking for a rough time sequence of events.  For example, in the case of a double spend attempt, and the double spender is colluding with the miner who is adding the next block.  At what point does a random node in the network, who is participating in mining, verify this was incorrect and flag the issue?
- Is it only the next miner who gets to add a block who detects this issue?
- Does each node only verify/run the transaction the next time they participate in mining or only when they solve the PoW and get to add a new block?
- Next time they are online?
- Is there a trigger such that a full node who may be idle, needs to run the contract code and verify?

What if the next N miners are also colluding?  Does it require just one miner to flag the transaction as incorrect or N+1?

Obviously, all nodes cannot run that transaction before another block is built, so i'm hoping there is a ballpark timeline of events.

Comment: A full node should verify every transactions that appears in a new block.

Comment: I am specifically asking for the order of operations and a timeline.  What if a node drops offline?  What if a node has a computer freeze?   All of these nodes cannot be in sync

Comment: When a node connects for the first time it will receive blocks from other nodes. For each block it will first perform basic verifications like if the parent block is already present, block difficulty, etc. If the basic verifications pass it will execute the transactions in the order they are present in the block. After performing all transactions it will check the resulting final state is correctly stored in the block header. If everything is ok the block is accepted.

Comment: There are some modes like geth's fast mode that will skip the transaction execution of old blocks and only run them for recent blocks. This is done to save time and storage space.

Comment: I am still not getting any remote answer on an example order of operations. If I have a smart contract - and I expect it to have run on every node, at what point has it run on 99% of the nodes?  Is there any indication? Do nodes verify the transaction prior to mining for the next block addition? After they win the Pow?  The next time they actually participate in a transaction on-chain?  Background task which verifies blocks even if they are not actively mining?

Comment: The exact meaning is a little different from what you expect. It doesn't have to be executed on 99% of the nodes. Instead it has to be executed on 50%+1 of the miners (not respect to the number of miners but the total hashing power). Only miners have incentives for executing contracts, and they should verify mined transactions before mining a new block or they may lose the block reward if the previous block was invalid.

Comment: Other non mining nodes are not required to execute transactions but accepting an invalid block can cause problems. Because other nodes will black list nodes that are propagating invalid block. So full node may execute contracts anyway to verify the block is valid.

Comment: The principle of operation is quite different and hard to accept. Q1 - each node decides for itself. Q2 - Double spend is not detected. It never happened. Each node works from an unambiguous order of events it believes. Q3: Every full node computes every transaction, not just miners. Q4: See Q3. Q5: A block arrives with an ordered transaction list. These transactions must be evaluated. Q6: It is not linear. All miners are competing for the privilege of ordering transactions for a brief period. The majority determines the truth. Q7: Not obvious and incorrect assumption. *Yes, they do.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a miner solves the proof of work puzzle on the block he/she is mining, he puts it in the block's header, and propagates it to the other nodes he knows about. They could be other miners, or other non-mining full nodes.

The new block is now being propagated. The nodes that receive the new block have to validate it.

Non-mining full nodes will do the following:

- Check the PoW in the block header is valid;
- Propagate the block to peer nodes;
- Check the state transitions in the block are valid.

Mining nodes do the same, but in a slightly different order, allowing them to start mining more quickly on the next block:

- Check the PoW in the block header;
- Check the state transitions in the block are valid;
- Propagate the block to peer nodes.

Checking the state transitions in a full 8Mgas block takes in the order of 100-200ms on a decent machine.

Onto your specific questions.

> I am not asking if all nodes run each transaction.

They do, to ensure their state is internally consistent. (There's actually game theoretical argument that goes against this. I've heard that some miners aren't actually checking the contents of the block are valid, and are just assuming it is to allow them a head start on mining the next block.)

> At what point does a random node in the network, who is participating in mining, verify this was incorrect and flag the issue?

It should be flagged by the miner's first set of peers, who should be validating the state transitions.

> Is it only the next miner who gets to add a block who detects this issue?

No, as above.

> Does each node only verify/run the transaction the next time they participate in mining or only when they solve the PoW and get to add a new block?

No, when they receive a newly propagated block.

> Next time they are online?

If they go offline, when they come back online, and before they start mining again, they'll need to sync back up to the chain head. Validation is part of this sync.

> Is there a trigger such that a full node who may be idle, needs to run the contract code and verify?

The trigger is that it'll have the new block pushed to it.

> Obviously, all nodes cannot run that transaction before another block is built, so i'm hoping there is a ballpark timeline of events.

In theory they do, else they don't know that they're building on a valid state.

Answer (score -1):

The transaction are only been checked during mining, so by the nodes who mines.
All the other nodes, when they receive the block, check if the solution, according to the difficulty, is correct for the block. So they only verify the solution provided by the miner. If it is correct, then they accept it, if not, it gets rejected.

You can find more about block validity in the yellow paper, part 4.4.2: http://yellowpaper.io/

Concerning execution order, I am not sure at all, sa I prefer sayig nothing. You should have a look into the yellow paper as well about it: http://yellowpaper.io/

Comment: So based on this no one has addressed my question.  The yellow paper is not obvious about this which is why I am asking the question here from someone knowledgeable about it.